# Data on car models, brands and type

Tags: cars

I'm looking for a database which is kept up to date (eg. monthly/quarterly updates) about cars. The dataset must contain the car brand, model and type (eg. SUV, coupe,...). All extra data is welcome. I would like to have the data at least on continent level, preferably world-wide.

I'm comfortable with a free sample paying if I'm satisfied with the sample.

Comment: this question is asked in several forms, see [tag:cars]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Car Models by Manufacturer, Category, and Year**](https://www.back4app.com/database/back4app/car-make-model-dataset)

A dataset with car models categorized by manufacturer, type (SUV, Sedan, etc), and manufacturing year. A developer is able to clone, connect, and download the dataset in a JSON format (transform to CSV after downloading). The dataset is open-source and provides detailed information about motor vehicles manufactured in the US between the years 1992 and 2020.

---

This [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172031/dataset-vehicle-make-model-year-free) links to a database someone put together and hosted on GitHub, although it sounds like it's fairly incomplete.

Comment: Thanks this looks pretty good. I'm also looking for images on the different models.